# Is there any way to get access to Chrome's theme favicons?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to use Chrome's default favicons.
For example (you can simply open them in Chrome):

- chrome://theme/IDR_HISTORY_FAVICON
- chrome://theme/IDR_EXTENSIONS_FAVICON
- chrome://theme/IDR_SETTINGS_FAVICON
- chrome://theme/IDR_PRODUCT_LOGO_16

When I used it as an image source nothing happened. Maybe Chrome blocked the access to the icons or this was not the proper way to use the icons. I tried to use "chrome://favicon/", but it didn't work with Extensions and Settings (strange, but it worked with History).

How can I use the built-in favicons as an image?
I would be also grateful if you could get me a full list of the Chrome's favicons, it must be in Chromium's source code, but I have no idea where to look.

(I'm using Chrome 19.0.1084.52)